# Export SharePoint Search results to Microsoft Excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-addin, search-results, export

I need a functionality to export search results to Excel for SharePoint. I've researched a lot and found many answers though no blog provides end to end solution. Best I could find is: Catch search object that's returned and work on it. I'm not sure how to proceed on it. Also, is it possible to make a generic App which when added, will provide a button to export to excel option?

Update:
At the moment I using REST to hit the server and parse objects. Problem is that I've to export 60,000 records and REST doesn't return more than 500 per search.

Environment: SP 2013 EE.

Comment: What exactly do you want to export? The managed properties, the binary documents? How will you choose what properties to include?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott CT targets multiple lists. So, only managed properties will be exported.

Answer (score 1):

Since search results are just JavaScript and HTML you could create a Control Template and Display Template that presents your results, then add your own feature to Export the data.

Look at something like this sample: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/12_initialization_loading/13_pro_load_csv.html

Any JavaScript that can serialize the data will work.

Comment: We are displaying results in tabular format. Is there a way to catch the search result object in SharePoint? Exporting current page isn't the solution since search results spans across multiple pages.

Comment: You could re-execute the query without paging using REST and dump the whole dataset using the same CSV export code.

Comment: We've more than 60,000 records. REST doesn't return more than 500 records.

Comment: OK, you didn't mention that. That's a totally different scenario.